# Angular 5 HttpClient - A get, a transformation, and a post, can't get it working

Tags: angular5, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

I have tried all sorts of permutations. What I am trying to do is perform a get in order to retrieve an object by Id, then modify a attribute of that object and then post it back, so that I am effectively updating the object.

here's what I tried:

```
  archive(orgId: number, id: number): Observable<Aircraft> {
    return this.http.get<Aircraft>('/api/organisations/' + orgId + '/aircrafts/' + id)
        .pipe(mergeMap( a => {
          console.log(a);
        return this.http.post<IAircraft>('/api/organisations/' + orgId + '/aircrafts/' + a.id, a).subscribe();
      });
  }
```

Result: ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

```
archive(orgId: number, id: number): Observable<Aircraft> {
    return this.http.get<Aircraft>('/api/organisations/' + orgId + '/aircrafts/' + id)
      .map((data) => {
      return data.current = false;
    })
        .pipe(mergeMap( a => {
        return this.http.post<IAircraft>('/api/organisations/' + orgId + '/aircrafts/' + a.id, a).subscribe();
      }));
  }
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'id' on boolean 'false'
and

```
restore(orgId: number, id: number): Observable<Aircraft> {
    return this.http.get<Aircraft>('/api/organisations/' + orgId + '/aircrafts/' + id)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap( a => {
          a.current = true;
          return this.http.post<IAircraft>('/api/organisations/' + orgId + '/aircrafts/' + a.id, a).subscribe();
        }));
  }
```

ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

The full error:

```
core.js:1448 ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:74)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:138)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:135)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:118)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:90)
    at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:151)
```

I just can't seem to get the map right, if I take the map out, it works, but then there's no point. I have also tried casting varous map results into observables, but it seems like the API sees right through my trickery, and continues to throw up the same error.

can anyone show me how this is supposed to work?

**EDIT** I have continued to play around with it - here is the latest incarnation:

```
  archive(orgId: number, id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<Aircraft>('/api/organisations/' + orgId + '/aircrafts/' + id)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(a => {
          console.log(a.constructor.name);
          console.log(a);
           a.current = false;
         return this.http.post<IAircraft>('/api/organisations/' + orgId + '/aircrafts/' a.id, a);
        }));   }
```

console.log(a.constructor.name) returns "object" - so useful

console.log(a) returns

[image: this console output]

Comment: Slowly, tell us what console.log(a); returns. Eventually (if it is) you just forget to `.json()` or `.json().results` Also tell us which line returns the error.

Comment: sure: console(a) returns the Aircraft object, whose member, 'current' is a boolean. The error line is in core.js and gives out a lot of other framework lines, which I have now posted into the answer - although they don't provide much help to me, they might to others. I suspect that the error is being thrown in the http.post line

Comment: actually, it looks like its being thrown at the beginning of mergeMap. I was under the impression that the http get passes on an Observable, which is meant to be a legal entry for mergeMap, or so the doco says, anyway.

Comment: Yeah the problem is definitely at `mergeMap` that's why it would help if you share the result of `a`. I normally prefer to do things like this in the back end so I´m not that used to mergeMap.

Comment: This is what I have ended up doing, but its pretty messy. I now have an api with a REST endpoint "/api/organisations/3/aircrafts/22/restore", which puts a verb at the end, so its no longer a resource, but a command. I was hoping to avoid that sort of thing. I promise you the result of a, is just an object, which I have now provided, but, as you can now see, its not very interesting to the problem.